# jQuery get input box value from get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my plan here is to get it display input box value as what it gets from GET method
If I post submit, I will be getting url as http://site.com/#search/**test**.
So... how can we get those two values to connect? Display GET method result in our textbox?

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" value="currentgetmethod" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form_data = ($(this).serialize());
    window.location.hash = form_data.replace('=','/');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?  Your JS seems to work okay.

Comment: Everything works fine. I'm looking something, like gmail has. search inputs value == to current get

Comment: You mean like when the page loads?

Comment: If i was to have index.php?search=wasd. That wasd would have to stay inside that input box even after refresh

Comment: Something like(just for you to understand) <input type="text" value="<?php $_GET[]; ?>" name="search">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load just do this:

```
var values = window.location.hash.slice(1).split('/');
$("[name=" + values[0] + "]").val(values[1]);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. 1 more thing. 
If i change from: http://localhost/#search/test to http://localhost/#search/orsomething and CLICK ENTER. It wont change, I have to click refresh. Any fix for that?

Comment: You can bind that to the `hashchange` event like `$(window).on('hashchange', function () {`